# dropdown menus and on message communication (js chrome extension(

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a dropdown menu and its value determines the behavior of my chrome extension. I need to use its value in my content.js file, and therefore need to communicate its value from popup.js to content.js. There are a few similar posts about this but none have seemed to solve my problem. Below is my code and the commented out parts are different versions of my attempts. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or what I need to do differently.

**popup.html**

```
<select id="language-dropdown" data-placeholder="Choose a Language...">
  <option value="English">English</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

**popup.js**

```
/*chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function ( msg, sender, sendResponse ) {
    if ( ( msg.from === 'content' ) && ( msg.action === 'getLanguage' ) ) {
        var language = document.getElementById("language-dropdown").value;
        //var language = $('#language-dropdown').find(":selected").text();
        sendResponse({ language: language }); 
        return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
});*/

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if ((request.from === 'content') && (request.action === 'getLanguage')) {
        sendResponse({
            language: document.getElementById("language-dropdown").value });
    };
});
```

**content.js**

```
var word_dict;

/*chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ from: 'content', activate: true });
setTimeout(function () {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { from: 'content', action: 'getLanguage' }, languageDict);
}, 100);*/

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { from: 'content', action: 'getLanguage' }, languageDict);
});

function languageDict (language) {
    var lang = language.language;
    console.log('Language:' + language);
    if (lang === "English") {
        word_dict = window.english_word_dict;
    } else if (lang === "German") {
        word_dict = window.german_word_dict;
    } else {
        Error; //other languages must be filled in here once available
    }
}

/*var ddm = document.getElementById("language-dropdown");
//var selectedLanguage = ddm.options[ddm.selectedIndex].value;

if (ddm.value === "English") {
    word_dict = window.word_dict;
  } else if (ddm.value === "German") {
    word_dict = window.german_word_dict;
} else {
    Error;
}*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can't use `chrome.tabs` API:
  only `chrome.runtime`, `chrome.i18n`, `chrome.storage` API are allowed.
- `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` purpose is to send a message **to** the content script so it should be used in the browser_action popup script or in the background script.
- The popup runs only when shown so it can't receive any messages when it's hidden.

---

The solution is two-fold:

1. save the language choice in `chrome.storage` so the content script uses it when a web page loads.
2. listen to the storage `onChanged` event in the content script and apply the new language choice in all tabs where the content script's instances run.

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["storage"]
```

popup.html:

```html
  <script src=popup.js></script>
</body>
```

popup.js:

```js
document.getElementById('language-dropdown').onchange = function () {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({language: this.value});
};
```

content.js:

```js
let language = 'English';
chrome.storage.sync.get('language', data => {
  renderLanguage(data.language);
});
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(changes => {
  if (changes.language) {
    renderLanguage(changes.language.newValue);
  }
});
function renderLanguage(lng) {
  if (!lng || lng === language) return;
  language = lng;
  // update DOM using the new language
  // ..............
}
```